# Delphi - generic type check if is created

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have the following class definition

```
  TBase<T> = class
  public
    class var Inst: T;
    class function GetClone: T;
  end;
```

And I want to check if the class var Inst is assigned.

```
class function TBase<T>.GetClone: T;
begin
 if TBase<T>.Inst = nil then //- error here. Trying with Assigned(TBase<T>.Inst) is also nor recognized.
    TBase<T>.Inst := TBase<T>.Create;
end;
```

How can I check if my class variable is assigned?

Comment: What is `T`? If it is a class you could add a constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to constraint the generic parameter in order to check for `nil`. For example:

```
TBase<T: class> = class //...
```

That way `T` must be `TObject` or any descendant of it, so you can check for `nil`.

Without the constraint `T` can be `integer` or any other value type that doesn't support `nil`.

Comment: modify TObject with class, and I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: You should also include the [`constructor` constraint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Constructor_Constraints) to ensure that `T` actually implements a parameterless `Create()` constructor: `TBase<T: class, constructor> = class //...`